# Error reading a key file from s3 - Not all bytes were read from the S3ObjectInputStream, aborting HTTP connection

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk

I have a key file which I kept on s3 and trying to read it using Java SDK and use it in subsequent steps to decrypt other files.The decryption code requires to pass the key file as InputStream. My code is shown below. I am getting below error. What I need to change to fix the error ?

WARNING: Not all bytes were read from the S3ObjectInputStream, aborting HTTP connection. This is likely an error and may result in sub-optimal behavior. Request only the bytes you need via a ranged GET or drain the input stream after use

Code :-

```
    S3Object object = s3Client.getObject(bucket, key);

    InputStream ret  = object.getObjectContent();

    return ret;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `object.getObjectContent()` you get an `InputStream` to work with - the actual implementation is `S3ObjectInputStream`.  Unfortunately if something goes in your application before you finish reading the S3ObjectInputStream, you need to call the abort() method to avoid the problem.

If you can change your code to return `S3ObjectInputStream` instead of `InputStream` and then call abort() on it if a problem occurs.